# 'tail -F *.log' but with systemd

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

With normal syslog I can go to `/var/log` and run `tail -F *log` if I am not sure which log something is logged in.

Is there an equivalent for `systemd`?

**Background**

I am trying to debug a server. It crashes without leaving a trace. I am hoping that using the `systemd` version of `tail -f *log` that I can see log messages that are logged (but not yet written to disk) when the server crashes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to use is the `journalctl` command. For example, if I want to get updated log entries on the service vmware, I would run this (f = follow, u = unit/service name):

```
journalctl -f -u vmware.service
```

Here's how you can get the full system journal. I use this command for my updated system logs (f = follow, x = Add message explanations where available, b = since boot):

```
journalctl -fxb --no-hostname --no-full
```

Comment: On small systems, you may want to check the memory usage of `journalctl` - it seems the `-b` option saves you some RAM, but even still, it's a considerably bigger process than a simple `tail` would have been :-(

Answer (score 2):

If you are just looking to simply follow logs then this should do the trick

```
journalctl -lf
```